# Поиск по маске из List<string>

Tags: c#

У меня есть список файлов которые хранятся в `List<string>` для поиска.
Я хочу добавить в этот список имя файла по маске расширения
`"beta.*"` - где * рандомное расширение файла, но он так не работает.

```
static List<string> myFiles = new List<string>() 
{
   "backup", "recovery", "tested", "beta.*"
};
```

Подскажите как можно сделать рандомный поиск из `List<string>` ?

Comment: Это список, значения которого захардкожены. Что и как именно вы пытаетесь добавить?

Comment: @aepot, сразу думал добавить в `List<string>` чтобы он искал по маске, но такого я понял что не бывает. И надо как-то по другому, но вот как хз.

Comment: Я лично так и не понял: кто и что тут ищет, и кто этот он, который так не работает?

Comment: List это список, он коллекция, может хранить данные, он не может ничего искать и про маски ничего не знает.

Comment: То, что вы хотите сделать, надо делать на этапе поиска, например `var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\", "*.*")`, где `*.*` это паттерн поиска. Если всеж вы хотите это сделать с уже имеющимся листом, то подключайте `Regex` например, пишите под него выражения, а потом делайте `var files = myFiles.Where(x=>Поиск по Regex паттерну)`, будет то, что хотите.

Comment: [File globbing in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/file-globbing)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, вот это уже интереснее. Если у меня в `List<string>` будут расширения типа: `beta.*` и `*.extension`, то какую мне использовать регулярку под эти расширения?

Comment: @ZidoX С регулярками не ко мне, я вам лишь идею дал, дальше уж сами. По сути, там достаточно написать то, что хотите найти, без звезд, но может попутно зацепить то, что не хотите (например `.js` возьмет еще и `.json` ибо в нем есть `.js`), это все надо учесть. Можете попробовать вариант, что дал выше Александр, вещь выглядит интересно.